# Subreport in SSRS ignores parameters of main report

Tags: service, reporting-services, parameters, reporting, subreport

I have a report which looks at the general ledger accounts and a subreport that drills down into the account to see all the transactions that happened in that account.  The parameters on the subreport that should tie to the main report are period (month), account and department.  I hard code the year in both reports to current year.  The period is year to date so it should return all periods up to and including whatever was chosen as a parameter.  The subreport is totally ignoring the period though.  It does bring the correct account/department entries but for example, if I choose 8 as the period, I want to see Jan through Aug entries.  Instead, sometimes it comes back as 1-3 and sometimes it comes back at 1-6.  Never 1-8.  If I put period 1 in, I just want to see Jan but again, it gives me either 1-3 or 1-6.  It makes no sense.  Hope someone can help!
Thanks,
Kim

Comment: What's the expression you are using to filter the query with your parameter? Are you passing the parameter to the subreport?

Comment: In my subreport my where clause is WHERE        (ledger_account = @account) AND (dim_1 = @dim) AND (fiscal_year = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (fiscal_period <= @period)

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter and didn't get the rest of my answer.  Yes I am passing the parameter to the subreport.  I'm linking dim to dim, acct to acct and period to period.

Comment: It sounds like it should be working but if it isn't there must be some issue somewhere. Is your Fiscal_Period based on the Month of your entry date?

Comment: Yes.  Period is month of entry date.

Comment: Have you checked your **subreport properties** to make sure that the Parameters are mapped correctly? Make sure your subreport parameter is mapped to your main report parameter and not a field. If that doesn't help, add the parameter in a text box so you can see the value it is using.

Comment: That worked!  I was linking to the field, not the parameter.  I'm used to Crystal Reports and only recently started converting our Crystal reports into SSRS.  Thanks so much!

Comment: are the datatypes same ?